# I'm having a difficulty solving this linear algebra problem. I would appreciate any help!

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

So we are having a matrix $A$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2&0&0\\
0&1&1\\
0&1&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I already found the eigenvalues which are $\lambda_{1}=2$ (of multiplicity $2$) and $\lambda_2=0$

Then I found the eigenvectors which are
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
x_3\\
x_3\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

And

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
-x_3\\
x_3\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Here I'm stuck. As far as I know, because we have $3\times 3$ matrix we need $3$ vectors, but here I have only $2$, which means that our matrix is not diagonalizable. That's why I think I have a mistake somewhere.

The initial queation is to find a diagonalizaing matrix $S$, and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that

$$S^{-1}AS=D$$;        $$A=SDS^{-1}$$

Comment: $(1,0,0)$ is also an eigenvector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find eigenvectors for the multiple eigenvalue we need to solve the homogeneous linear system

$$(2I-A)\vec x=\vec0\implies\;\text{the system is}\;\; y-z=0\implies y=z\implies \left\{\;\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\;\right\}$$

is a basis for the eigenspace $\;V_2\;$ , so you must have made a mistake when evaluating this eigenspace

Comment: Thank you so much! But does it still mean that the matrix is not diagonalizable?

Comment: No it is diagonalisable, since for each eigenvalue, its geometric multiplicity is equal to its algebraic multiplicity.

Comment: @krszyoscezio It is what Bernard said, or in other words: you matrix is diagonalizable because there is a basis formed by eigenvectors of the matrix.